# How is "data" supplied to the jQuery deferred object's done method?

Tags: jquery, ajax

When using a callback function inside of jQuery's deferred object, specifically with an ajax call, the function is given three arguments, `data`, `responseText`, and `jqXHR` object.  I'm having trouble following the specific logic that provides those arguments.  How are they fed to an anonymous function inside of a method?  Where is  `data` defined?

Example:

This works and logs the data:

```
deferredObj
    .done(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
```

This does not work, data is an unknown variable:

```
defferedObj
     .done(console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This does not work, data is an unknown variable
>
> `defferedObj.done(console.log(data));`

When you use `console.log(data)` as callback, the function is called immediately when it is encountered.

So, at the time when the `log` is called, `data` variable is `undefined`.

This is like calling a function `.done(myFun())`.

If you want to call function `console.log` as callback function with the parameters passed automatically you can call it as

```
defferedObj
    .done(console.log.bind(console));
```

---

> How are they fed to an anonymous function inside of a method? Where is  data defined?

You can think of the asynchronous function defined as follow:

```
function asyncDoSomething(param, callback) {
    // Do something asynchronously here to get the data from somewhere
    // Maybe DB/Network, etc.

    // When processing is completed and data is retrieved
    callback && callback(data);
}
```

Comment: You mean it is called before even the `.done()` event is triggered?  Where is the `data` variable being defined?

Comment: @Preston Yes, because you're calling the function it is directly called. You're not passing a function, instead you're passing the returned value from the result of calling the function